# Complilation problem with gradle - apereo cas server

Tags: gradle, ldap, cas

Hello, I am currently setting up a Apereo CAS server in a local network which will have to authenticate users belonging to ldap directories so that they can then connect to an applications server.
A Windows Server 2019 Active Directory is the gateway to the WAN.

Environment:

- Windows Server 2019 with Active Directory and DHCP, routing and DNS installed which make the link between the WAN and the LAN; IP: 192.168.100.10
- LDAP Server on Centos 7 on the LAN registred on the Active Directory (no ssl certificate generated); IP: 192.168.100.50
- CAS Server on Debian 11 on the LAN (no ssl certificate generated); IP: 192.168.100.101
- All pinging between each other;

I'm following this process to install and configure the cas server:
https://www.esup-portail.org/wiki/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=972292097

This is my build.gradle configuration file:

[build.gradle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nOfLg.png)

This is my cas.properties configuration file:

[cas.properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ByObv.png)

This is the result of the ./gradlew clean command:

[compilation.error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RoRov.png)

This is the error line on build.gradle:

[error_line-build.gradle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nzMeO.png)

I don't understand where the error comes from. thank you to enlighten me.

Moreover, if someone has a detailed procedure, which describes the environment and the prerequisites, recent and educational to install a CAS server for Centos 7, I am interested

Answer (score 1):

In older CAS versions you had to specify the version numbers in your dependencies, but now the build script gets the right dependencies automatically for you. I see you're using the old `casServerVersion` instead of `project.'cas.version'`

---

To make it work you need to do two things:

First remove all versioning from your own declared dependencies.
So remove these parts for each line you added:

- `:${project.'cas.version'}`
- `:${casServerVersion}"`

That way your dependencies look something like this:

`implementation "org.apereo.cas:cas-server-support-ldap"`.

Second move all of your declared dependencies **above** this line in your build.gradle:

`if (project.hasProperty("casModules")) {`

The build script will now automatically get the right dependency versions.

---

As for guides/tutorials/etc check these out:

- https://paulchauvet.github.io/deploying-cas/
- https://fawnoos.com/blog/ (tutorials by Misagh Moayyed: The apereo chairman/CAS maintainer/dev)